# Is a subset of a normal subgroup is a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

If M is a normal subgroup of G. Then let N be a subset of M. I tried to prove that it is a subgroup. If 'a'  belongs to N, to show 'a-1'  belong to N. But I can't show that it is true. May I know is it a subgroup or not. And what if Na=aN for all a belongs to G then is N a subgroup?

Answer (score 2):

Why should $N$ be a subgroup? If you take $M = G$ then any subset would be a subgroup, which is clearly wrong if $G$ is not the trivial group.

PS: The new part of the question also does not hold: If $G$ is abelian and non-trivial then we have $aN = Na$ for any subset $N \subseteq G$, even if $N$ is no subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$ be our group over addition, then any subgroup $N=n\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup, so we take $n=5$ and get $N=5\mathbb{Z}$, a subset of this subgroup is $M=\{5n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. However $M$ is clearly not a subgroup because it has no inverses over addition.

Comment: So it is possible that a subset to be normal but not being a subgroup

Comment: No, if it is normal it is a subgroup by definition, your question however was that a subset of a normal subgroup being a subgroup, which is not always the case.

Comment: That subset M which you defined seems to be a normal. If for any 'a'  belongs to Z then,      aMa-1=M.

Comment: To be normal it must first be a subgroup to begin with.

Comment: This depends on your definition: You could also define an arbitrary subset as normal if it is normalized by the whole group under the conjugation action. A normal subgroup is then, as the name indicates, a subgroup which is also normal (as a subset).

Comment: If one goes by that then it's accurate.

Comment: Why? When their are subsets satisfying every properties.

Comment: whose/whats subsets? THe subset does not satesfy the criteria to be a group.